# Compute SQNR (Signal to Quantization Noise Ratio)

Tags: snr, quantization

I'm studying the quantization of an audio signal and in particular the **SQNR** (*Signal to Quantization Noise Ratio*).

The book on which the study says that:

[image]

where:

- *N* is the number of bits in the digital representation
- *V* indicates that the signal voltage varies between *-V* and *+V*.

I don't understand how these calculations were carried out. 
Is SQNR not simply the "digital" version of the RMS?
I know the RMS is calculated as power signal divided by power error, am I wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The signal voltage is a sinusoid signal variant from $-V$ to $+V$, thus the RMS value

$$V_{rms} = \frac{V}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2^N \Delta V / 2}{\sqrt{2}}$$

because $2V = 2^N\Delta V$ where $\Delta V$ is quantization step.

Quantization noise is modeled as uniform random variable in $[-\Delta V /2, +\Delta V /2]$ thus its standard deviation is $V_n = \Delta V / \sqrt{12}$.

SQRN is defined as $\mathrm{SQNR}=\frac{V_{rms}^2}{V_n^2}$

$$\sqrt{\mathrm{SQNR}}=\frac{V_{rms}}{V_n} = 2^N \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\mathrm{SQNR}_{dB}=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{V_{rms}}{V_n}\right) = 20\log_{10}\left(2^N \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) = 6.02N + 1.76$$

You must have mistyped your question.